# Update nested array inside nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of recipes below, in the structure of an array:

```
[
  {
    "brandName": "Piatto",
    "_id": "1234",
    "name": "Test",
    "rate": 89,
    "baseQuantity": 1000,
    "baseUnit": "gm",
    "details": [
      {
        "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b",
        "quantityInRecipe": 0,
        "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2a",

        "quantityInRecipe": 0,
        "costOfRawMaterial": 0
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "brandName": "Piatto",
    "_id": "5678",
    "name": "Macaron Shell",
    "details": [
      {
        "_id": "5f397abb59ad0ba71f27fa93",
        "rate": 12,
        "quantityInRecipe": 121,
        "costOfRawMaterial": 14.52,
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f397adb59ad0ba71f27fa94",
        "quantityInRecipe": 122,
        "costOfRawMaterial": 17.08
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f36cccc875da6156c9a0782",
        "quantityInRecipe": 330,
        "costOfRawMaterial": 19.8

      }
    ],
    "baseQuantity": 573,
    "baseUnit": "gm",
    "totalCost": 51,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I want to update the value of the "id 5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b" in the first object(ID:1234).

So far I am able to update the array details of the object "Test" (ID: 1234) separately, which is at index 0 with the below code..

```
 
    let tempArray = state.recipeBasicRecipes[index].details;

    let objIndex = tempArray.findIndex(rec => rec._id === id);

    const updatedObj = {
      ...tempArray[objIndex],
      quantityInRecipe: e.target.value
    };

    console.log(objIndex);

    const updatedArray = [
      ...tempArray.slice(0, objIndex),
      updatedObj,
      ...tempArray.slice(objIndex + 1)
    ];
```

My objective is to update the details array in the first object with the updatedarray.

Comment: Why not use `find` rather than `findIndex` and just update the found object directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to reassign the `updatedArray` back to the sub-array of the first element in `recipeBasicRecipes`:

```
state.recipeBasicRecipes[index].details = updatedArray;
```

The reason that is necessary is, your `updatedArray` is actually a separate, new instance of an array (rather than a reference to the `details` sub array that your start with) which means the `details` sub-array needs to "point to" (or reference) your new `updatedArray` array to achieve the desired result.

Another "immutable" approach to this problem would be as follows:

```js
const basicRecipe = state.recipeBasicRecipes[index];

/* Obtain new details sub array with updated quanitity data */
const updatedDetails = basicRecipe.details.map((detail) => {
  
  if(detail._id === id) {
    /* If we're iterating the detail matching "id", apply new quantity */
    return {
      ...detail,
      quantityInRecipe: e.target.value
    }
  }
  else {
    return detail
  }
  
});

/* Apply updated details to updated recipe */
const updatedRecipe = {
  ...basicRecipe,
  details : updatedDetails
}
  
/* 
Apply updated recipe to component state 
this.setState({
  ...state,
  [index] : updatedRecipe
})
*/
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot..That was missing piece..:-)

Comment: Thanks @Darce Denny For the suggested approach will surely incorporate this..